# How in insert image path in Wordpress database that will display product image in wp admin not on front end?

Tags: wordpress

```php
$insert = $wpdb->insert( $prefix."posts", array("post_title" => $posTitle,"post_content" => $postContent,"post_status" => "publish","post_type" =>"product"));

// select products ID
$select = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID AS productsId FROM ".$prefix."posts WHERE post_title='".$posTitle."'");
//echo $select[0]->productsId; die();
// insert Image in pots and product attribute meta posts table
$insertImg = $wpdb->insert($prefix."posts",array("post_status" =>"inherit","post_type" => "attachment","guid" => $postGuid,"post_parent" => $select[0]->productsId ));
```

I need a small, which table and column I need to insert to display product image in wordpress admin, I insert products by query in wordpress rather than insert product by admin.

Comment: Any one know its easy solution

Comment: Where in the admin area ? at the post list ?

Comment: product -> Edit product -> at right side product image(feature image )

Comment: I have a live image path 
http://www.cardkingdom.com//product_images/1/9/4/6/6/8/40161_large.jpg
I want to be store this path and display as product image in admin

Comment: yes ! My focus is that to insert products by query not manually aslo write code for that but image didn't work for me in admin so I need to be use store image in database and display in admin

Comment: there is no need to use query for that - wp has a lot of functions that you could use . But please specify ( modifying the original question ) what exactly is the process you want .. where the images come from and how they are to be inserted .. ( is it from a user ? meta box ? folder ?? from admin ? from front end ?

Comment: source come form a site I fetch data from a site using file_get_contents to fetch data and filter data by using regex but now i want to store filter data in database that create a new product which is work but with out product image (feature image ) in admin

Comment: here is with demonstration http://smartzonewebservices.com/regex.png

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress featrured image is actually a meta field called `_thumbnail_id` , and as such , it is located in `wp_postmeta` table

example:

```
meta_id post_id meta_key meta_value
874 3767 _thumbnail_id 3841
```

In the example above ,the `meta_value` is actually the ID of the attachment ..

what you did in your query , is actually only insert an **attachment** .

```
$insertImg = $wpdb->insert($prefix."posts",array("post_status" =>"inherit","post_type" => "attachment","guid" => $postGuid,"post_parent" => $select[0]->productsId ));
```

Now you need to make that attachment a featured image by adding the relevant `post_meta`

Now, honestly , I am not so good in direct SQL queries ( just basics ) but if you are running the whole process on WP - well, it has different methods to achieve that .

1 - `set_post_thumbnail( $newpostid, $attach_id );` where the parameters are quite self - explanatory ,

2-  `update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);` - also self explanatory ..

Both will actually do the same ..

Now , Like I said before - I have already done such a process like you described many times  , but not with direct queries ..

The usual flow for me was using only wp built-in functions , for example :

```
$newpost = array( 'post_title' => $fullname, 
                        'post_content' =>'',
                        'post_status' => 'pending',
                        'post_category' => array(5),
);

    // Create the post
    $newpostid = wp_insert_post($newpost);

// $filename should be the path to the file ( upload directory for example ) 
            $filename = $dest_path;

            // Check the type of tile. We'll use this as the 'post_mime_type'.
            $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

            // Get the path to the upload directory.
            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            // Prepare an array of post data for the attachment.
            $attachment = array(
                    'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ), 
                    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
                    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );

            // Insert the attachment.
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $newpostid );

            // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

            // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

            // And now make it a featured image..
            set_post_thumbnail( $newpostid, $attach_id );
```

I hope this will set you on the right track ..

Comment: what I have done yet I have insert data using query
1. I insert post with post_title='abcd',post_content='abcd' post_status='publish',post_type='product'
2. insert post with post_parent='ID of above post that i craete in step 1',guid='http://www.cardkingdom.com//product_images/1/9/4/6/6/8/40161_large.jpg',post_mime_type='image/jpeg'
3. insert postmeta meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and meta_value= ID craete in second step.

Comment: this work great for me
do u have idea how to upload images from external url and save it into upload folder I do some stuff with success but image is not proper format and contain error

Comment: well, first of all, if this is resolved, you might want to accept the answer to mark as resolved ( the little `V` you see on the left of the answer ) or vote up or both.. And if you have another question, please post it as such ( a new question )